# How do I know what my username/password is for SQL PLUS?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to set up an Oracle SOA Suite environment with docker containers according to this website -> https://svgonugu.com/2018/03/12/docker-containers-for-oracle-soa-suite/

I got to a point where I have to connect to a database with this command: `sqlplus sys/fusion@//172.17.0.1:1521/soadb as sysdba`

But it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

So what am I doing wrong here? I have not given a username or password during the whole process.

Answer (score 2):

> I have not given a username or password during the whole process.

Why not? It is clearly written on that site, right before the step where you try logging in with sqlplus.

> - Execute `docker exec <<container id>> /opt/oracle/setPassword.sh <<pwd>>` to reset password for SYS user.